# C array of objects that allow for dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

If I have a class with dynamic allocaton like `std::vector`. How much sense does it make to create an array with elements of that object?

I tested the following:

```
std::vector<int> array[2];

array[0].push_back(10);
array[0].push_back(20);
array[0].push_back(30);


array[1].push_back(40);
array[1].push_back(50);
array[1].push_back(60);

for (auto x : array[0]) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

for (auto x : array[1]) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Which outputs the values correctly. However is this actually undefined behavior? Array elements are located contiguously in memory. When a `std::vector` object is initialized without specifying size, it doesn't allocate any memory. So when we create an array with two elements, is any memory allocated at all? When we then add new elements to `std::vector` are we writing outside of the array bounds?

Comment: The vector doesn't store the allocated memory inside the vector object.  A vector contains an int for the size and a pointer to some heap-allocated memory and maybe a couple other things.  So the array of vectors is fine because when the vector grows it is the heap memory that is being reallocated and none of that is inside the vector object (and therefore not inside the array).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Oh yeah that actually makes sense. So we are practically creating an array of pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no undefined behavior here.

> How much sense does it make to create an array with elements of that object?

This is entirely up to you, and your design considerations.  It's perfectly fine to have an array of vectors.

> So when we create an array with two elements, is any memory allocated at all?

Yes, memory for the *array* is allocated.

> When we then add new elements to std::vector are we writing outside of the array bounds?

`std::vector` allocates memory dynamically.  A default-constructed vector may or may not allocate memory.  This is implementation-dependent.  Internally, the vector is probably just holding pointers.

Some implementations may be smarter than this, by switching from a fixed number of elements with no dynamic allocation to using dynamic allocation if the requirements exceed that.  `std::string` implementations commonly do this, by repurposing the internal pointer storage to hold string data instead.

Note that if you are pushing some number of elements onto a new vector, it's good practice to call `reserve` on that vector to avoid unnecessary reallocations as it grows.

Comment: I imagine a vector is unlikely to have the equivalent of Small String Optimisation, because it would only be useful for, say, 1 int, or 8 `char`s. For strings that's not necessarily uncommon, but for vectors...

Comment: I don't see why this is such a crazy notion.  Imagine `std::vector<char>`.  The standard doesn't rule it out, as far as I know.

Comment: No, it's certainly not ruled out, but small strings are common, whereas if you have a `std::vector<char>` it's probably some buffer for binary data which tends to be bigger, and for any other `value_type` it's probably entirely useless. There's just not a compelling reason to implement it (and to take the cost of switching between the storage mechanisms that goes along with it).

Answer (score 1):

An object of the type `std::vector<int>` has a fixed size that depends on its implementation.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> array[2];

    std::cout << "sizeof( std::vector<int> ) = " 
              << sizeof( std::vector<int> )
              << '\n';
                  
    std::cout << "sizeof( array = " 
              << sizeof( array )
              << '\n';
                      
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    array[0].push_back(10);
    array[0].push_back(20);
    array[0].push_back(30);


    array[1].push_back(40);
    array[1].push_back(50);
    array[1].push_back(60);
    
    std::cout << "sizeof( std::vector<int> ) = " 
              << sizeof( std::vector<int> )
              << '\n';
                  
    std::cout << "sizeof( array = " 
              << sizeof( array )
              << '\n';
                      
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( std::vector<int> ) = 24
sizeof( array = 48

sizeof( std::vector<int> ) = 24
sizeof( array = 48
```

When you are adding new elements to the vectors their sizes are not changed and correspondingly the array size also is not changed.

The program is well-formed.

The class template `std::vector` contains as its data member a pointer to a memory where it places its elements. If there is no enough memory the vector reallocates it. But the size of an object itself of the vector type does not depend on the reallocated memory.